# SQL query is very slow for certain parameters (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-performance

I am making a `PHP` backend API which executes a query on `MySQL` database. This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM $TABLE_GAMES WHERE 
 ($GAME_RECEIVERID = '$userId'OR $GAME_OTHERID = '$userId')
  ORDER BY $GAME_ID LIMIT 1"
```

Essentially, I'm passing `$userId` as parameter, and getting row with smallest `$GAME_ID` value and it would return result in less than 100 ms for users that have around 30 000 matching rows in table. However, I have since added new users, that have around <100 matching rows, and query is painfully slow for them, taking around 20-30 seconds every time.

I'm puzzled to why the query is so much slower in situations where it is supposed to return low amount of rows, and extremely fast when returns huge amount of rows especially since I have `ORDER BY`.

I have read about parameter sniffing, but as far as I know, that's the `SQL` Server thing, and I'm using `MySQL`.

*EDIT*

Here is the `SHOW CREATE` statement:

`CREATE TABLE`games`(`
ID`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
SenderID`int(11) NOT NULL,`
ReceiverID`int(11) NOT NULL,`
OtherID`int(11) NOT NULL,`
Timestamp`timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17275279 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`

Here is the output of `EXPLAIN`

`+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref | rows | extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | games | NULL | index         | NULL | PRIMARY | 4   | NULL | 1     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----+------+-------+`

`id     select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra

1   SIMPLE  games   NULL    index   NULL    PRIMARY     4   NULL    1   19.00   Using where`

I tried prepared statement, but still getting the same result.

Sorry for poor formatting, I'm still noob at this.

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the definition of your table; that is, the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` . We may be able to suggest indexes for you to add.  And, please clarify: The query you showed us only returns a single row. You said it can return 30K rows; is that from a different query?

Comment: Those indexes will not help _that_ query any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is being slow because it cannot find a matching record fast enough. With users where a lot of rows match, chances of finding a record to return are much higher, all other things being equal.

That behavior appears when `$GAME_RECEIVERID` and `$GAME_OTHERID` aren't part of an index, prompting MySQL to use the index on `$GAME_ID` because of the ordering. However, since newer players have not played the early games, there are literally millions of rows that won't match, but have to be checked nonetheless.

Unfortunately, this is bound to get worse even for old users, as your database grows. Ideally, you will add indexes on `$GAME_RECEIVERID` and `$GAME_OTHERID` - something like:

```
ALTER TABLE games
ADD INDEX receiver (ReceiverID),
ADD INDEX other (OtherID)
```

PS: Altering a 17 million rows table is going to take a while, so make sure to do it during a maintenance window or similar if this is used in production.

Comment: Hi, thx for the help! So as far as I can understand, adding indexes to certain columns makes database sort the data in a way that it enables it to get results faster. Ideally I should index every column that I use as search parameter, right? Would there be any negative consequences to adding indexes, other than, I guess, increased db file size?

Comment: It also increases insert times (although most often by a negligible amount), as indexes have to be re-computed as each new record is put in its designed place as per each index.

Depending on what exactly you search for and what indexes you add, there's also the possibility that they aren't all used to their potential, or, on the contrary, some might be useless. For a bit more reading, if you're interested, [here's a nice article](https://medium.com/@User3141592/single-vs-composite-indexes-in-relational-databases-58d0eb045cbe) on the subject.

Comment: Hey, just added those indexes and now all queries are super fast, magic! Interestingly, it only took 2 minutes :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)

Comment: @asd123 Please post A) current EXPLAIN of your query and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE games; for analysis.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `EXPLAIN` to analyse the performance of the query.

i.e.

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM $TABLE_GAMES WHERE 
  ($GAME_RECEIVERID = '$userId'OR $GAME_OTHERID = '$userId') 
   ORDER BY $GAME_ID LIMIT 1"
```

The `EXPLAIN` would provide the information about the select query with execution plan.
It is great tool to identify the slowness in the query. Based on the obtained information you can create the `Indexes` for the columns used in `WHERE` clause .

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_list)
```

This would definitely increase the performance of the query.

Comment: Alas, `EXPLAIN` says what is happening, but not what to do to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the query after the interpolation?  That is, is this what MySQL will see?

```
SELECT * FROM GAMES
     WHERE RECEIVERID = '123'
        OR OTHERID    = '123'
     ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1
```

Then this will run fast, regardless:

```
SELECT *
    FROM GAMES
    WHERE ID = LEAST(
         ( SELECT MIN(ID) FROM GAMES WHERE RECEIVERID = '123' ),
         ( SELECT MIN(ID) FROM GAMES WHERE OTHERID    = '123' )
                    );
```

But, you will need both of these:

```
INDEX(RECEIVERID, ID),
INDEX(OTHERID, ID)
```

Your version of the query is scanning the table until it finds a matching row.  My version will

1. make two indexed lookups;
2. fetch the other columns for the one row.

It will be the same, fast, speed regardless of how many rows there are for USERID.

(Recommend switching to InnoDB.)